# Segfault on mprotect increasing memory

Tags: c, linux, memory, memory-management, virtual-memory

I am working on a computer with 8GB of memory with Ubuntu 20.04.  I read a 4 GB file into memory, and now I want to create a virtual memory buffer using the memory that remains after the 4GB file.  After reading the 4GB file, System Monitor says I have approximately 2.5 GB available.

In order to know how much memory I can use under program control, I wrote a program that uses "less /proc/meminfo  | grep MemAvailable" to determine available memory.  That returns a value that very closely matches what System Monitor says is available.

I subtract an arbitrary 100MB because I don't want to use all available memory.  That leaves just over 2.4GB for my buffer size.  System Monitor says I have more than that available.

I create a virtual memory buffer with protection set to 10MB.  I increase that to the requested size with mprotect:

```
int grow_mmap(void * address, size_t new_length) {

    int64_t ret_val = mprotect(address, new_length, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE);

    char buf[1024];
    strcpy(buf, strerror(errno));
    printf("%d --> %s\n", errno, buf);  

    if (ret_val != 0) {
        printf("Error increasing memory: %s\n", strerror(errno)); }

    return ret_val;
```

}

But at the line "strcpy(buf, strerror(errno))" I get this segfault message:

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__GI___pthread_rwlock_rdlock (rwlock=0x7ffff7fa4980 <__libc_setlocale_lock>)
at pthread_rwlock_rdlock.c:24
24  pthread_rwlock_rdlock.c: No such file or directory.

I query errno:

(gdb) p errno
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__errno_location () at ../csu/errno-loc.c:25
25  ../csu/errno-loc.c: No such file or directory.
The program being debugged was signaled while in a function called from GDB.
GDB remains in the frame where the signal was received.
To change this behavior use "set unwindonsignal on".
Evaluation of the expression containing the function
(__errno_location) will be abandoned.
When the function is done executing, GDB will silently stop.

If I lower the requested amount to 100 MB or 500 MB then it succeeds.

I have used this program many times, but never with a buffer size > 500MB.

So my question is:  under the circumstances described above, how can I determine how much of the available memory I can use with mprotect?  This is mission critical software, so no other userspace programs are running that would use memory.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Could you use memory mapped files and just skip the reading into memory part entirely? That will lean on the OS to buffer/cache what it wants, and shouldn't exhaust any memory as any buffers are trivially evictable.

Comment: I am working with an end user who will use my code to pass in a large array of data, so it's not an option to skip reading in the data.  Also, that would just transfer the problem to the data read.  I may use a renewable buffer of smaller size, and write it to disk each time it fills up, and start again from the start of the buffer.  But ideally I would  like the whole thing in memory.

Comment: Ideally we have infinite memory, but such is not the case. You may want to test memory mapped vs. in memory as the performance difference might be negligible, but the on-going memory cost of the in-memory version may not be worth it.

Comment: What do you mean by "memory mapped vs. in memory?"  What's the difference?

Comment: *I increase that to the requested size with mprotect* ???  `mprotect()` doesn't allocate memory for you.  If `mprotect()` doesn't return any error, and you're not pointing it to change the permissions on memory you allocated and know the address of, you're stomping on something else.

Comment: I mean [`mmap`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) and the like instead of `fread` and such.